# zcat file not working for gzip file

Tags: linux, bash, gzip

I have a .gz which I need to merge and do other manipulations with (without compressing it), but I am having trouble just using zcat or gzip -dc or awk, for example when I pass these value to less -S like this:

```
awk '{print $1}' <(gzip -dc file.gz) | less -S
```

I get the incorrect column printed. When I use just less -S to view the file, only the last few columns are printed. So I thought it was a problem with the delimiter, but I have tried importing in R some lines (it is too big to import the whole file), and it seems to be space delimited since all the columns are showing up when I do this:

```
x=read.table("file.gz", header=T, nrows=100)
```

But how do I read the lines correctly to use this file with zcat?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Question totally unclear. "All works fine", then what is "not working"?

Comment: 1 possibility is you've saved MS WIndows formatted files, and are now trying to view them in *nix? If so you either have to resave at your source, or add `| sed 's/^M$//' | less ...` where `^M` is 1 char, created by pressing the Ctrl-V key combo, followed by the Ctrl-M key combo. Good luck.

Comment: this zcat file.gz | sed 's/^M$//' | less... doesn't work but thanks for the reply anyway...

Answer (score 1):

If you want the whole line to be printed, try $0.

> awk '{print $0}' <(gzip -dc file.gz) | less -S

If you want specific columns to be printed, use -F to specific field separator. For example, if you want first field of ':' separated fields from each line (like in /etc/passwd), try this command.

> awk -F':' '{print $1}' <(gzip -dc passwd.gz) |less -S

Comment: I had tried this too but with no success...the first line prints only the last two columns of the file...I ended up importing it into R after a long time and re-saving it...but thanks anyway.